# Multi select listview not working with more than one component inside list item

Tags: android, xml, listview, multi-select

I have a CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL enabled ListView. It is working perfectly fine, on long press the list item is getting selected when there is only one TextView enclosed within a RelativeLayout in the List item XML.

But When I am adding a checkbox to the item XML then I am not able to select the list item with a long click.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Working list item XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/todoNoteTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Non working list item XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/todoNoteTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkboxTodo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any Clue?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
your_text_view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            //Check or uncheck the CheckBox.
            if (!your_check_box.isCheck())
               your_check_box.setChecked(true);
            else your_check_box.setChecked(false);

            return false;
        }
});
```

Listen to a long press (long click here) and on long press event set the current check box or uncheck it. This should resolve the issue.

Comment: No this isn't the requirement. Checkbox check / uncheck is independent of the list item selection. You can think of like checkbox check will make the task complete where as list item selection will enable for deletion of the whole list item.